# Data is not getting inserted in database correctly from baked URL in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am a beginner to cakephp and started to look into the tutorials after successfully installing and configuring. I created a database in MySQL and created a table `users` that contains the attributes `email, password, created` and `email` being the primary key.

I ran a command `bake all users` in order to auto generate code. When I tried to add new user by going to `http://<path>/users` it is only asking for `password` field but not `email` field and an empty space is getting inserted for `email` field. And when I tried to add another user it is showing an error that value of primary key should be different. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show some generated code... And set id for that table, did you create table without `id`?

Comment: As suggested by Insane Skull, please post your code and you will have more chances to find help. See which is the better way to ask at stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @skywalker yes i didn't created any `id`. It was there in the tutorial but I ignored it as I don't want. Is it necessary?

Comment: All tables should have `id` field, and your `email` field can be unique if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

run the following command

```
cake bake all
```

and choose your database, hope it helps

if it still doesn't work , may be your path is not set.
refer the following link 
http://nurelm.com/running-cakephp-command-line-tools-in-windows/

Right click on my computer>>Properties>>Change settings(in that workgroup settings area) >> Advanced .. etc set the path and then it should work

Comment: `password` field is getting inserted but the problem is for `email` field.

Comment: Check the view once, you may not have described the view for email, and the error you're getting might be because your code doesn't ask for email and is trying to insert a blank value for email. E-mail being primary key, should be `NOT NULL`
Anyway,
It would help if you paste your code here